Validation, required if 2 other fields have specified values
I have validation in Laravel 10 that contains validation for company_description. I want it to be required when two other fields have specified values. I got this code:
'company_description' => [
                'string',
                'nullable',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    if (request()->input('offer_type_id') == 1 && request()->input('use_default_company_description') == false) {
                        if (empty($value) || $value == '') {
                            $fail('Company description is required.');
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],

but its not working. If nullable is removed its working, but I need this field to be nullable. What am I doing wrong?

You're checking for empty($value) || $value == '', which is what nullable handles, so your Rules overlap.

@TimLewis I dont get it. So how I can force company_description to have value if offer_type_id is 1 and use_default_company_description is false, and be nullable otherwise?

Your $fail() code can never be triggered if you keep nullable, since you're checking for empty($value) || $value == '', which nullable already handles... You need to remove nullable and handle it manually in your rule, probably as an else { ... } statement.

Use the withValidator and a sometimes to conditionally add the required rule.
company_description' => ['string']
public function withValidator($validator) {
        $validator->sometimes('company_description', 'required', function ($input) {
            return $input->offer_type_id == 1 && $input->use_default_company_description == false;
        });
    }


nullable allows the field to be null, which oppose the custom validation rule you are trying to apply when offer_type_id == 1 and use_default_company_description == false. When nullable is present, it takes precedence
'company_description' => [
        'string',
        'nullable',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $offerType = request()->input('offer_type_id');
            $useDefault = request()->input('use_default_company_description');
    
            // If offer_type_id is 1 and use_default_company_description is false
            if ($offerType == 1 && $useDefault == false) {
                // Check if the company_description is null or empty
                if (!request()->filled('company_description')) {
                    $fail('Company description is required.');
                }
            }
        },
    ],

Kindly note the following

request()->filled(): This helper checks if the input is present and not empty or null
The fail() method will only be triggered if company_description is empty or not provided when offer_type_id == 1 and use_default_company_description == false

